# Font Awesome Icons Weirdly Not Displaying In Shopify Store

Tags: html, css, shopify, font-awesome, liquid

After spending hours going around in circles. I've reached a level of frustration where I need an outside perspective.

See this code here and how it produces exactly what should be expected.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<p class="fa fa-check-circle fa_custom"> Verified</p>

<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

**Then if I enter this code within a Shopify liquid file.**

[image]

**The output is this:**

[image]

Why isn't one of the icons showing?

I've made this demonstration to highlight my problem. I'm experiencing this with a few other font awesome icons as well. I'm designing pages in HTML / CSS in sublime. Then when I take this code into a Shopify store. The icons can't be seen. I've replicated this problem in multiple stores.

It's very strange. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Do you still have this issue if you place the <link> in the <head> of the page?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's becoming beyond frustrating.

Comment: Everything above is just to highlight the problem. The link is usually in the <head> tag as it should be.

Comment: check your developer console, additionally make sure that your font awesome installation includes the icon you want to use

Comment: The developer console doesn't show any error or anything. The code above works? So the icon must be in that link, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the first icon inside a p-statement.
Maybe one of your CSS-files is changing the font.

Tried this one?

```
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa_custom"></i> Verified <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

Comment: Yes! That seems to do the trick. It was the hit of a new perspective that I needed. Thanks!